# convert from string to list of Ascii decimal numbers

Tags: python, function

how to make a function to convert the input string into List of ASCII decimal numbers.

```
str="Johan"
for i in str:
    print(ord(i), end=' ')
```

Comment: `[ord(i) for i in my_string]`?

Comment: so, what is the problem with the code you show?